# Tail program output to stdout or stderr

Tags: bash

I have a piece of bash code that works fine.

```
for thing in "$things"; do
    output=$(my_program "$thing" 2>&1)

    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "$(echo "$output" | tail -1)"
    else
        echo "$(echo "$output" | tail -1)" 1>&2
    fi
done
```

The idea is to echo the last line of the output from the subcommand to stdout if it worked and to stderr if it didn't work.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Answer (score 2):

Don't quote `$things`:

```
for i in "1 2 3 4"; do
   echo "i=$i"
done
i=1 2 3 4
# Better is
for i in 1 2 3 4; do
   echo "i=$i"
done
i=1
i=2
i=3
i=4
```

When `my_program` is written well, errors are written to stderr and normal output to stdout. Your bash code is working well, so the program already uses the right returncode.
Can you change the `my_program`? When you can add an option `-s` (silent/summary), the program can make sure only 1 line is written to stdout (when OK) or stderr (when NOK):

```
for thing in ${things}; do
    my_program -s "${thing}"
done
```

Or without for-loop

```
printf "%s\n" ${things} | xargs -L1 -I{} my_program -s "{}"
```

When you can't change `my_program`, or you don't want to, move the special handling to a function and remove the additional `echo` commands:

```
tail_my_program() {
   output=$(my_program $* 2>&1)
   if (( $? == 0 )); then
      tail -1 <<< "${output}"
   else
      tail -1 <<< "${output}" >&2
   fi
}

for thing in ${things}; do
    tail_my_program "${thing}"
done
```

Your original solution and my function have a small bug: When `my_program` writes something to stdout after writing an error message to stderr, the stdout message is selected after an `exit 1`. This might never happen.